# DDWRT PPTP VPN - Single Network, Single Subnet - Partially Working Config

Tags: vpn, pptp

So I have the following configuration, and it works - sort of:

Primary Router - Edge device (UBEE router from provider).

- This router is the gateway and is assigned 192.168.0.1
- This router provides DHCP for the range 192.168.0.102-192.168.0.254
- Note: This configuration is designed to allow me to statically assign network resources (specifically, a NAS, and a failover machine for me to remote into so I don't have to drive to the office if the VPN is down). This also gives me a range of IP's to devote to the VPN that I elected to keep on the same subnet (per an old walkthrough I read a long time ago).
- VPN (IPSec/L2TP) Passthroughs are all enabled
- Port 1723 is forwarded to the Secondary Router

Secondary Router - Linksys E1200v2 running DDWRT v24-sp2

- This router is linked to the primary router from LAN to LAN (not WAN to LAN)
- This router is assigned 192.168.0.2 as the Local IP with a Gateway and DNS of 192.168.0.1 (the Primary Router)
- Connection Type is Disabled
- DHCP Server is Off (the Primary Router handles all DHCP)
- VPN Service PPTP Server Enabled (as well as Multicast and MPEE)
- DNS is Primary Router
- VPN Server IP is 192.168.0.50
- VPN Client Range is 192.168.0.51-59 (max assoc. 9 clients)
- CHAP-Secrets are all setup and verified working and here's where the fun starts.

THIS VPN SETUP WORKS. Sort of. This might sound really strange, but it depends on what network I am trying to VPN from.

If I set my cell phone as a Mobile Hotspot, and connect to that as my Wifi router. I can access this VPN from wherever I am on my laptop.

However, at my house (and many employee's houses), this does not work. I can literally sit here at my house, jump on my wifi, try and connect to the VPN and it will not work. I can then disconnect my laptop from my home network, jump on my Cellular Hotspot network, and the VPN works fine.

Can anyone think of a reason why this is?

Please keep in mind my setup is based on an old guide that I cannot even find anymore. I'm not looking to re-invent the wheel over here. I just need this VPN to work for people and it obviously DOES work somewhat, so I don't want to have to tear it all down and start over. If I have to, I have to, but I am sincerely hoping it's something hilariously stupid.

Comment: You should tear it down and start over anyway. PPTP has been known to be insecure for well over a decade, and it can't be made secure. It is not recommended for anything even remotely sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You often have to enable a helper for PPTP to pass through a router on the client side. If you have DDWRT at home it would be on the Security->[VPN Passthrough](https://www.dd-wrt.com/demo/VPN.asp) page. It will be different for each specific router / firmware.

[image]

TP-LINK : [What’s VPN Passthrough?](http://www.tp-link.com/sa/FAQ-558.html)

D-LINK : [DIR 615 Emulator with VPN Passthrough settings](http://support.dlink.ca/emulators/dir615_revA/110/adv_dmz.htm)